# how properly pass constructor parameters in require() statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The module.exports in app1.js exports a new object. I don't want to modify this file by removing NEW keyword but pass constructor parameters from app2.js

```
// app1.js
class Polygon {
  constructor(par1={}, par2=null) {
    console.log(par1, par2);
  }
}

module.exports = new Polygon();
```

So is there a way to pass it from file app2.js, especially JSON parameter:

```
// app2.js
var polygon = require('./app1');
```

Assume it would look like this:

```
var polygon = require('./app1')({"xxxx": "zzzzz"}, yyyy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can export a function that returns a new object like this

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(par1={}, par2=null) {
    console.log(par1, par2);
  }
}

function getObject(param1, param2){
    return new Polygon(param1, param2);
}

module.exports = getObject;
```

they way you want to use it will work.

```
var polygon = require('./app1')({"xxxx": "zzzzz"}, yyyy);
```

Comment: this will return a new instance every time though right? seems like he wants to use a singleton

Comment: yes, I think that's the need since a singleton values can be set later on so I `assumed`

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is, instantiate the singleton, then export a function that set's props on the singleton and returns it

```
// app1.js
class Polygon {
  setProps(par1, par2) {
    this.par1 = par1;
    this.par2 = par2;
  }
}

const singleton = new Polygon();

function getSingleton(props) {
    singleton.setProps(props);
    return singleton;
}

module.exports = getSingleton;

// app2.js
var polygon = require('./app1')({"xxxx": "zzzzz"}, yyyy);
```

Comment: 1 for keeping singleton

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the params in your export statement:

```
// app1.js
class Polygon {
    constructor(par1={}, par2=null) {
        console.log(par1, par2);
    }
}

module.exports = (par1, par2) => {
    return new Polygon(par1, par2);
};
```

And to consume:

```
var polygon = require('./app1')({"xxxx": "zzzzz"}, 'yyyy');
```

Comment: doesn't this introduce a different behaviour than `module.exports = new Polygon(part1, part2)` ? Due to the caching nature of NodeJs, wouldn't your example create multiple `Polygon` instances, instead of just one (singleton).